# Make Regex only filter table based on a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, livesearch

I made a phonebook where I work for internal use. All results are shown in a table. I used to just have this as my function to filter on that table:

```
function LiveSearch() {
    $('input#srch-field').on('keyup', function () {
        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.srch-table tr').hide();
        $('.srch-table tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
    });
}
```

But my users are apparently unhappy with this requested function, so they want a filter instead. So I have made a dropdown that supposed to act like a filter. I was then looking at my function and was thinking "How can I modify this, to make it work generally the same?", so I came up with this:

```
function LiveSearch() {
    $('input#srch-field').on('keyup', function () {
        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        var e = document.getElementById("srchFilter");
        var filter = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (filter === 'all') {
            $('.srch-table tr').hide();
            $('.srch-table tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();
        } else {
            $('.srch-table tr[id=' + filter + ']').hide();
            $('.srch-table tr[id=' + filter + ']').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is that every value in my select:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="srchFilter" class="form-control">
        <option value="all" selected="selected">No Filter</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="department">Department</option>
        <option value="private-phone">Private Phone</option>
        <option value="work-email">Work Email</option>
        <option value="work-phone-land">Work Phone Landline</option>
        <option value="work-phone-mobile">Work Phone Mobile</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Corresponds to a Column ID in my table. But if my filter is anything but `all` it simply doesn't do any filtering whatsoever. I might just be misunderstanding how the regex works. Could anyone shed some light on it?

**EDIT**

The code for my Table as request:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" id="customtable">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-xs-4" id="name">
                    Name<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="col-xs-4" id="title">
                    Title<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="col-xs-4" id="department">
                    Department<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
                </th>
                <th style="display: none;" id="private-phone">
                    Private Phone
                </th>
                <th style="display: none;" id="work-email">
                    Work Email
                </th>
                <th style="display: none;" id="work-phone-land">
                    Work Phone Landline
                </th>
                <th style="display: none;" id="work-phone-mobile">
                    Work Phone Mobile
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="srch-table" id="srch-table">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-12"><b>Please Wait...</b></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="fl-separator"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your table's code.

Comment: @31piy I have added it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you are assigning duplicate IDs to the table elements (as I sniff from your JavaScript code). IDs should be unique across an HTML page, and that's why your filter won't work as expected.

You can try to assign a class instead (or and HTML data attribute is recommended). So, for example, the `td` related to `name` will have a class `name` instead of id `name`.

And then, your JavaScript code can be changed like this, so that it can leverage `class`es instead of `id`s:

```
// ... code truncated for brevity

if (filter === 'all') {
  $('.srch-table tr').hide();
  $('.srch-table tr').filter(function () {
    return rex.test($(this).text());
  }).show();
} else {
  $('.srch-table tr').hide();
  $('.srch-table tr').filter(function () {
    return rex.test($(this).find('td.' + filter).text());
  }).show();
}

// ... code truncated for brevity
```

Note the use of dot selector which matches the `tr`s which only have `td`s with specified class.

**Bonus**: Since you're using jQuery, these lines:

```
var e = document.getElementById("srchFilter");
var filter = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

can simply be replaced by this line:

```
var filter = $("#srchFilter").val();
```

**Update**:

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/LLvzsqd1/) is a forked version of your fiddle which works.

Comment: So would I have to put those classes on my rows when I make them? They are made with another javascript function.

Comment: @Vipar -- Since the table columns contain specific details, and row is the collection of columns, the classes need to be applied on `td`s.

Comment: That didn't exactly work right. When I choose "Department" for example, and then write "IT", I can see that it seems to be shifting row values around, making the table completely unusable :/

Comment: @Vipar -- Can you please create a working fiddle or something? It is too cumbersome to think about all the possibilities of it not working right.

Comment: I tried to set up an example, but it won't listen to my text field for some reason :/ https://jsfiddle.net/5pkaxdnu/4/

Comment: I also tried to use your jQuery way of finding the Select value, but it returned as "undefined" so I just used what I had before.

Comment: @Vipar -- You didn't include jQuery in your fiddle. Plus, there was a bug in my code which I corrected. Please see my updated answer, it includes a link to a working fiddle.